# How to specify that the return value of a function must be iterable with C++20 concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I've got a concept I'm writing that's meant to express "a type that can split a container into pieces", so this is what I'd *like* to write:

```
template <class Adapter, class Container>
concept Splittable = requires(const Container& shard) {
  requires requires (const SplitCriterion& criterion) {
    for (const Container& piece :  Adapter::Split(shard, criterion)) {}
  };
};
```

But, this fails because the for loop is not an expression.  I could do:

```
  requires requires (const SplitCriterion& criterion) {
    { Adapter::Split(shard, criterion) } -> std::convertible_to<std::vector<Collection>>;
  };
```

or:

```
  requires requires (const SplitCriterion& criterion) {
    { Adapter::Split(shard, criterion) } -> std::convertible_to<absl::Span<const Collection>>;
  };
```

But the first one ties the concept to a specific output type (std::vector), and thus inherits the requirements for std::vector on `Collection`.  The second option is more flexible but e.g. disallows returning a derived instance of `Collection`.

What's the canonical way to express this in a concept?

Comment: `std::range` or some specialization of that? In combination with `std::range_reference_t` if you need to iterate with that specific reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept for iterable is `std::ranges::range`:

```cpp
template <class Adapter, class Container>
concept Splittable = requires (const Container& shard, const SplitCriterion& criterion) {
  { Adapter::Split(shard, criterion) } -> std::ranges::range;
};
```

Now, that *just* expresses that it must be a range *at all*, it doesn't tell you anything about what the underlying type needs to be.

If you want to further expression that this gives you a range over a type that is convertible to `T`, we can add that as our own concept:

```cpp
template <class R, class T>
concept range_of = std::ranges::range<R> && std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>, T>;
```

which lets us adjust the initial answer to:

```cpp
template <class Adapter, class Container>
concept Splittable = requires (const Container& shard, const SplitCriterion& criterion) {
  { Adapter::Split(shard, criterion) } -> range_of<const Container&>;
};
```